# Impedir que classes modifiquem o estado de objetos

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern

Como impedir classes de modificar o estado de objetos de uma classe, ambos
Dentro de pacotes iguais e separados?

Assumindo que exista um pattern para projetar uma java class design que possa ou mesmo afete o estado dos objetos.

Comment: A pergunta tem a tag design pattern. Você quer saber se tem algum pattern para isso?

Comment: @IgorVenturelli, isso mesmo! No caso do Design pattern Observer se não me engano monitora o status de um objeto. Então, a forma que projetamos uma classe afeta o comportamento dos objetos.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve criar classes imutáveis, onde o estado do objeto não pode ser alterado após a sua criação.

`String` é um exemplo de classe imutável, dentre tantos outros.

```
public final class Person {

     private final String name;
     private final int age;
     private final Collection<String> friends;

     public Person(String name, int age, Collection<String> friends) {
         this.name = name;
         this.age = age;
         this.friends = new ArrayList(friends);
     }

     public String getName() { 
         return this.name;
     }

     public int getAge() {
         return this.age;
     }

     public Collection<String> getFriends() {
         return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(this.friends);
     }
}
```

Atributos `private` e `final` e sem métodos `set`.

Um ponto importante adicionado neste exemplo é o uso de coleções imutáveis.

Baseado [nesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5124054/5230740) resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Isso são objetos imutáveis onde depois de criado, o objeto não tem como alterar seu estado interno, e isso é obtido através de privação de formas de definição de atributos como por exemplo métodos acessores como o setX, outra convenção é deixar os atributos como `final` visto que não serão alterados.

E no caso de Composições deve-se ter uma forma de só haver acesso de leitura à essas instancias para essa classe e somente a classe externa podendo acessa-las .

Outra pratica é que se houver métodos que modifiquem atributos estes retornem um novo objeto criado.. Usando os atributos da atual instancia, e assim sempre gerando um novo objeto..

Então ou privar modificação dos atributos ou se puderem ser alterados retornar um novo objeto .